# How to log GPIO status of the pins from raspberry correctly?

Tags: python

I try to log the GPIO value of the raspberry pi lik this

```
logging.info("value is ", str(GPIO.input(21)))
```

error is:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 619, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 380, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "/etc/openhab/scripts/gpiomqttcontrol.py", line 80, in <module>
    logging.info("value is ", str(GPIO.input(21)))
Message: 'value is '
Arguments: ('1',)
```

Comment: `info` only takes one argument, you are giving it two. Create the string you want to pass.

Comment: Print to console or save to file are good ways to track what a program is doing.

If you particularly want to know the GPIO state you could look at Joan's PiScope which allows you to record GPIO states and plot them locally or on another device.